# Azure service fabric with ApplicationGateway

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

i   have  Service   fabric  Cluster  Running   on  Azure ,i  have   deployed   Application   to  Service   Fabric.

Now  i  want  to  use  azure  Application  Gateway on  this  Scenario   like   Request   First  served  to  Application  Gateway   and  then   it  migrated  to   Fabric   Load  Ba-lancer.  I  am  Quite  Confused  on  this.How  to  meet   above  Challenges  with  ApplicationGateway

I also  able to  configure  ApplicationGateway  but   dont  have  IDea  how   to  use  it  for   service  fabric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Azure Application Gateway offers layer 7 load balancing capabilities, SSL offloading, layer-7 routeing, cookie based session affinity, URL routeing and able to host multiple web application. Azure Application Gateway requires its subnet; sometimes it is confusing if you are not familiar with Azure VNet and Subnet segmentation.

First what you need to understand is the architecture pattern, how Microsoft Application Gateway would play a part in.

I have written some detail series documenting my journey throughout Azure ServiceFabric.

I would suggest you go through these posts, and it will explain Architecture viewpoint for having Application Gateway in front of Service Fabric Cluster.

Irrespective of Application Gateway, you would need Internal Loadbalancer or External Loadbalancer (depends on your topology).

1. [Cloud Architecture Pattern: Azure Service Fabric and Microservices - Part 1 (Physical Architecture)](https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/services/cloud-architecture-pattern-azure-service-fabric-and-microservices-part-1-physical-architecture/)

   - [How to implement Application Gateway with Azure Service Fabric](https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/services/cloud-architecture-pattern-azure-service-fabric-and-microservices-part-1-physical-architecture/#application-gateway-and-web-application-firewall)
2. [Also try to understand how it is going to impact, security architecture of your implementation](https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/services/cloud-architecture-pattern-azure-service-fabric-and-microservices-part-3-security-architecture/)

Also, I would recommend you [Reverse proxy in Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#special-handling-for-port-sharing-services).

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure your meaning, but you could create sf cluster and related resources using ARM teplates. Thats what I have done. I created appgw, cluster, vmss etc.  In the virtualMachinesScalesets networkProfile you must configure the ApplicationGateway back endAddress pool instead of configuring loadBalancerBackendAddressPools. The appgw must exist before vmss deployment. You don't necessarily need lb at all. Appgw can handle the load balancing for you. Even though internal lb would bring in some nice additional features, which you could utilize later on...

I have to admit that these things are quite poorly documented...

Comment: Hi @jpkk ,
I agree with you that everything ServiceFabric is poorly documented.
You mentioned that totally removing the load balancer and using ApplicationGateway instead is possible but you would lose out on some nice additional features. What are these features?

If you use both Application Gateway with the Load Balancer, what would that look like? Am I correct in thinking the request would look like the following?
http**s**://secured.example.com -> AppGW -> http://mycluster.westus.azure.net:19008/MyApp/MyService/ -> LB -> ReverseProxy -> Node_x